# 'Resource me does not exist' API error while calling /v2/me

Tags: linkedin-api

I receive the error "Resource me does not exist" when I tried to call the URL GET: /v2/me.

GET: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture)

Token received from: https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

Authorization URL:

```
$url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
        .'?response_type=code'
        .'&client_id='."77uuvjhz11mi71"
        .'&redirect_uri='."http://localhost/linkedin"
        .'&state=123123123'
        .'&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social';
```

Request:

```
...
$linkedin->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
...
$this->setMethod("GET");
$this->setUrl("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture)");
$this->setHeaders([
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$this->accessToken,
]);
$resp = $this->sendRequest();
```

Response:

```
{#81 ▼
  +"serviceErrorCode": 0
  +"message": "Resource me does not exist"
  +"status": 404
}
```

The API functions:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->ch = curl_init();
}
public function sendRequest()
{
    curl_setopt_array($this->ch, $this->options);
    $result = curl_exec($this->ch);

    if (curl_errno($this->ch)) {
        throw new Exception("Error ". curl_error($this->ch), 1);
    }

    $json = json_decode($result);

    return $json;
}
public function setMethod(String $method)
{
    $method = strtoupper($method);

    if ($method === "POST") {
        $this->options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
    }

    return $this;
}
public function setUrl(String $url)
{
    $this->options[CURLOPT_URL] = $url;

    return $this;
}
public function setHeaders(Iterable $headers)
{
    $this->options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;

    return $this;
}
public function getAccessToken($code)
{
    $this->setMethod("POST");
    $this->setUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken");
    $this->setPostFields([
            "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
            "code" => $code,
            "redirect_uri" => "http://localhost/test",
            "client_id" => $this->clientId,
            "client_secret" => $this->clientSecret,
    ]);
    $resp = $this->sendRequest();
    $this->accessToken = $resp->access_token;
}
```

Comment: What type of error do you get in your callback function? Share some code please so we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi, I changed the question and added the code as well as the detailed response that I getting from the server.

Comment: Probably a permission issue. Check if you required these when created the access token: r_basicprofile, r_liteprofile (the tokens contain the permissions). You can also try to make a request with curl:  `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer ...TOKEN...' 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me'`

Answer (score 2):

The late response coming through,

I encountered a similar issue when making an API call to LinkedIn while using python and python's requests package.
In my case, I solved the issue by using a **GET** request. I had been trying to make the API call using the **POST** request type which made the resource non-existent.

Here is a link to the docs, they've given an example of how the URL should look like:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/profile-picture

Comment: I have same issue and amplify on GET method is my mistake too. Thanks for the helpful answer.

Comment: But get next error > Not enough permissions to access: GET /me

Comment: Hello @NamGVU. You're welcome. On the second error, kindly add some context.